# Git: deploy to OpenShift

Tags: git, deployment, openshift

I have PHP/Laravel/JS project in Git repository at Bitbucket.

The project should be deployed to OpenShift via their Git-based deployment system. They create a repo for your app. You `git clone` it. When you need to deploy just `git push` and OpenShift does the rest:

- stops the app (web-server);
- writes project files and configs (nginx.conf, for example) to the proper locations;
- performs custom post-deploy actions (which for Laravel at the very least are: `composer update` and `php artisan migrate`);
- restarts the app.

Cool, but:

- *.php, nginx.conf, custom post-deploy scripts, etc. should be pushed to both OpenShift and Bitbucket;
- minified *.js, *.css -- OpenShift only;
- raw *.js, *.scss -- Bitbucket only;
- gulpfile.js, Vagrant’s config, and other dev staff -- Bitbucket;
- Laravel’s cache,  IDE config -- neither OpenShift, nor Bitbucket.

What’s the best way to have it done? Two .git-openshift and .git-bitbucket (with different origins) instead of one .git? What about .gitignore? Don’t use OpenShift’s deployment system? Which tool should I use instead? Or, maybe, use Hg instead of Git for Bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

If you want different things in two different repositories then I suggest you actually create two separate git repositories. Then, you can have a custom build script which puts your compiled/minified files into a separate folder/repo.

Another option is to have an `orphan` [production branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/1.7.3.1) on your current bitbucket repo, and have your production code committed to that branch.

```
git checkout --orphan production
# You can delete all your files, they're still safe on master branch
git rm -rf .
# Ignore the stuff you don't want on openshift
git add .gitignore
# You need to make an initial commit
git commit -m "Initial production commit"
```

To set your [deployment branch](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-deployments.html#configuring-which-branch-to-deploy) on openshift

```
# 1. Set the deployment branch with the rhc command line tool
$ rhc app-configure <app> --deployment-branch production
# Every time you push to openshift, push your production branch instead of master
$ git push openshift production
```

Example workflow:

```
# Start from master branch
git checkout master
# Run your compilation scripts (whatever generates your production files)
./my-build-script.sh
# Then switch over to production branch
$ git checkout production
# Your changed files are still here, check it with git status, then add them
$ git add my-production-files/*
$ git commit -m "Add new built feature"
$ git push openshift production
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I'm afraid my (dumb) way of thinking is completely diffrerent from yours (correct one). What do you mean saying: "and have your production code committed to that branch"? Well, now I have production branch with no history and single file .gitignore commited to it. And I have master branch with another .gitignore and the code ready to deploy. `git what` should I do before `git push origin production`?

Comment: @user3368115 check my edits, I have added a possible workflow

Comment: As I wrote in my original question I have 4 kinds of files: BB, OS, both, neither. Your example workflow solves the problem with files of kind "OS", but not "both". OK, `git checkout production` doesn't remove from work tree OS-files (autogenerated), so I can add-commit-push them. But `git checkout production` also reverts both-files (*.php) to their production versions, which are already deployed. And I want to deploy their master versions.

Comment: You can always `git stash`, then checkout to production, then `git stash pop`. This should do it? But like I said, I would personally have two different repos